# How can I "break" a list comprehension in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

To prepare for a functional programming exam in Haskell, I'm rewriting recursive functions to list comprehensions (without using high order functions like map and filter), a task which will likely be on the exam.

I refactored this function that I wrote as a solution to an exercise which takes a list and an element and appends the element if it is not yet contained in the list from

```
noDupsApp :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
noDupsApp [] y = [y]
noDupsApp [x] y = if x == y then [x] else [x,y]
noDupsApp (x:xs) y
    | x == y = x:xs
    | otherwise = [x] ++ noDupsApp xs y
```

to

```
noDupsAppComp :: Eq a => [a] -> a -> [a]
noDupsAppComp xs y 
   | [x | x <- xs, x /= y] == xs = xs ++ [y]
   | otherwise = xs
```

This does seem to work as far as I can tell, but while thinking of the solution, I asked myself if there was a way to 'break'/ 'return' a function in Haskell. If there was such an option, I could break as soon as two elements are the same and then compare the produced list to 'xs', which would increase the efficiency (if 'y' is contained and not at the end). Other answers to a similar question also suggested using conditions, but that would lead to an iteration over the whole list as well.

Is there a way to break list comprehensions (or a simpler way to write this function with a list comp, but without using high order functions)?

Comment: Have you looked at `elem`? It checks if an element is in a list.

Answer (score 5):

Your code `[x | x <- xs, x /= y] == xs` already "breaks" when the first `y` is found. The first list will produce an element which is not `y`, when the second one has a `y`. This will immediately "break" from `==`, returning `False` early.

This is due to the lazy implementation of `==`, which scans the two lists and stops immediately after the first difference is found.

As an alternative, instead of checking `[x | x <- xs, x /= y] == xs`, you can check whether `[x | x <- xs, x == y] == []`. This also "breaks" early, and is equivalent to `` y `notElem` xs `` (also breaking early).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there a general way to "break" a list comprehension, or is using conditions the go-to method?

Comment: @YeuhYeuh There is no general way to "break". Lists are often generated lazily, so all we have to do is ensure that consumers (`==` in this case) stop reading from the list as soon as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension maps and filters all generated inputs when needed and Haskell's mathematical notation will not let you break that from the inside.

But from the outside context it often turns out that no further processing is needed and `runhaskell` will lazily skip unnecessary constructions and evaluations.

Ruling out the straightforward `elem y xs` test due to its lack of a list comprehension and the `any(==y)xs` approximation for its use of a higher-order function, i note following your style

```
xs +? y = if []<[y|x<-xs,x==y] then xs else xs++[y]
```

costing as little as

```
xs +? y = if or[x==y|x<-xs] then xs else xs++[y]
```

which you can incidentally [codegolf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/19255/tips-for-golfing-in-haskell) into

```
xs+?y=xs++[y|and[x/=y|x<-xs]]
```

lending the question whether the most stupid of all list comprehensions

```
xs+?y=xs++[y|notElem y xs]
```

were not sufficient.